# get the element the view event is bound to in the callback

Tags: backbone.js, event-handling, jquery

In Backbone, its pretty obvious how to make click events, but I'm having a hard time getting the actual element representing the selector to which the event was bound.

Do I have to check if I have it or go up the DOM via `$(ev.target).parent()`, or is there a simpler way?

Markup example:

```
<div data-action="handle">
  <div>This is the click event target.</div>
</div>
```

Backbone view example:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click [data-action="handle"]': 'handle'
  },

  handle: function(ev) {
    // ev.target doesnt match up with the actual selector above
    // How do I get $element such that:
    // $element.data('action') === 'handle'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the backbone uses event delegation. If you will try to get

> ev.target

it will get you the element where the event actually occurs i.e. the inner DIV.

To get the above working use:-

> ev.currentTarget

This will give you the element where you have actually attached the event.

Answer (score 0):

Another answser is that the element catching the event is available via `this`.

This won't be the case if you used `bindAll` on your callback though